# Why can login Facebook without OAuth?

Tags: c#, windows, facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm using windows phone and try to integrate Facebook with my App.
But all I found that the login mechanism is using OAuth 2.0.
Could anyone explain why Microsoft embedded People hub and  Microsoft Facebook App(XAP) can login without OAuth.
Are they using the WebAPI instead of the OAuth?

Thanks.

Comment: i guess there are deals between Microsoft and Facebook, using secret channels, just like iOS 6's native Facebook features...

Answer (score 0):

Try [Parse](https://parse.com/products/social#resources) I've used it on iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.  It's super easy to integrate, free and you'll get access to all of Facebook's API.